# * ngIf show div conditional value (less than)

Tags: angular, typescript

I have an input with a numerical value, then that value is multiplied by 2 and the result is displayed. For example 1000 x 2 = 2000. How do I show a div as long as the result is less than 122?

```
<input type="number" [(ngModel)]="valueInitial">
<div>Result: {{ valueInitial * 2 }}</div>
```

Comment: Did you try it with `*ngIf`?

Comment: I understand that with ngIf you can, but I want to know the logic

Comment: `<div *ngIf="valueInitial < 61">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say in the question you should use **`*ngIf`**

```
<div *ngIf="valueInitial * 2 < 122">Result: {{ valueInitial * 2 }}</div>
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-phqnnr?file=app/app.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks this worked for me, I will mark it as correct. An additional query I am trying to add the result as `valueFinal` and use that value in the ngIf, you can see my stackblitz please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrtvuv